# Examples of finite-dimensional, semisimple, non-separable $k$-algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopf-algebras, separable-extension

**1. Motivation**
Let $k$ be a field.
Apparently, any separable $k$-algebra is finite-dimensional and semisimple.
Using Maschke's theorem for Hopf algebras, one can prove that for Hopf algebras the following stronger statement holds:

> A $k$-Hopf algebra is separable if and only if it is finite-dimensional and semisimple.

I believe, if you replace "$k$-Hopf algebra" by "$k$-algebra", this proposition is wrong.

**2. Question**

- What are examples of finite-dimensional, semisimple, non-separable algebras?

Apparently, if $k$ is a perfect field any finite-dimensional, semisimple $k$-algebra is separable. Hence, any example has to be over an imperfect field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any prime $p$, the $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$-algebra (which is simple since it is a field) $\mathbb{F}_p(T)(\sqrt[p]{T})$ is such an example.

Comment: I understand $\mathbb{F}_p(T)(\sqrt[p]{T})$ is an algebraic function field. How is it defined? I have not been exposed to those fields, sorry - the wikipedia article wasn't useful in clarifying the notation either. The symbol $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ represents the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_p$, right?

Comment: You're right. If you prefer, you can see t the algebra above as the quotient  $\mathbb{F}_p(T)[X]/(X^p-T)$.